# How to pass parameter to different JSP pages?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JavaScript function that fires when a button is pressed. It looks like below:

```
   function fireGENURL(a){
    try{

        var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
            alert("Please select at least one file.");
            return false;
        }


        var filesList = [];
        var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        $fileChecks.each(function() {
            filesList.push($(this).attr('fileid'));
        });
        var count = $fileChecks.length;
        var stringArray = filesList;





        $('body').pWin("open", {
            x: 260,
            y: 47,
            height: 450,
            width: 881,
            title: "Generate URL",
            skinMode:'dialog',
            iframe:true,
            url: "file/url/genurl.jsp",
            data: {

            nodeID:stringArray

            },
            offResize:true,
            offMove:true,
            onTitle:false,
            offBottom:true
        });



    }catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }


}
```

It passes the nodeID to `genurl.jsp` to do it's function.Now I created another JSP page,called `view.JSP` and in this new JSP, I would like to :

```
long nodeID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("nodeID"));
```

to get it's value but because the data is not passing to this new JSP, how do I get the value for it?

### Edit

genurl.jsp:

```
<%
    //need to input logic to populate data on each row

    int counter=0;
    String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

        long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

        List files = fileFacade.list_items(file);
        for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
            Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
            Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
            // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());

            int count = 0;
            count++;
            long id= nd.getNodeid();



%>
    <script>
        function viewPDF() {
            try {

                $.post('repository/view/viewPDF.jsp', {
                        'nodeID':id
                    }, function (xml) {
                        var status = $(xml).find('status').text();
                        var msg = $(xml).find('msg').text();
                        var url = "about:blank";


                        url = "repository/view/viewPDF.jsp?nodeID="+id;

                    }


                    , 'xml');
            } catch (e) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }

    </script>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">
            <!--Display Checkbox   -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;
        </td>

        <td>
            <!--Display No   -->
            <% counter=counter+1;
                out.print(counter);

            %>


        </td>
        <td width="28%">

            <!-- Display Filename   -->
            <%=nd.getNodedesc()%>



        </td>
        <td width="100%">
            <!-- Display URL -->


            <%="http://localhost:8080/repository/view/viewPDF.jsp?nodeID="+nd.getNodeid()%>

        </td>


    </tr>

    </tbody>


<%}}
```

The above JSP page has no issue but I created another page called:

viewPDF.JSP:

```
<%

    long nodeID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("nodeID"));

%>


<head>
    <title>Sample</title>


</head>
<body>
<embed src="file_name.pdf?nodeID="+nodeID width="800px" height="2100px" />
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://localhost:8080/repository/view/viewPDF.jsp?nodeID=27453&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to pass the same nodeID that is passed to genurl.jsp so I am able to use that parameter to construct my viewPDF.jsp to view pdf documents based on parameter url.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter via query string

```
file/url/genurl.jsp?nodeID=stringArray
```

In JSP page you get value by

```
request.getParameter("nodeID")
```

Comment: I mean in my new View.jsp , I need to "grab" that nodeID value. Can this be done?

Comment: Please help please

Comment: Please check it

Comment: did you try window.location.href = url; after line url = "repository/view/viewPDF.jsp?nodeID="+id;

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: But I need to place it in viewPDF.jsp?